# Android OS framework - building individual executables as a shared object

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, operating-system

I'm just a beginner at this so bear with me -

I'm trying to modify some of the existing executable's in the framework in order to include them as a SO inside of an app (the modification allowing me to get a returned result from a method call rather than calling the executable at the command line),

Unfortunately, I'm finding it very difficult to isolate and build them.

For instance, the screencap executable:

http://androidxref.com/4.1.1/xref/frameworks/base/cmds/screencap/

You can see from the [screencap.cpp](http://androidxref.com/4.1.1/xref/frameworks/base/cmds/screencap/screencap.cpp) file it only uses (android) system headers:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#include <linux/fb.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

#include <binder/IMemory.h>
#include <gui/SurfaceComposerClient.h>

#include <SkImageEncoder.h>
#include <SkBitmap.h>
#include <SkData.h>
#include <SkStream.h>
```

While I can find these headers littered around the Android source tree it would be very time consuming to individually link them all for a custom build -

My question is, how do I work with the android source framework to build *just* the single executable without having to figure out the dependencies and linking?

Answer (score 3):

You can see there is an Android.mk under that directory.

So if you want to build that specific module: screencap.

Simply setup Android build environment by:

```
export SHOW_COMMANDS=1
. build/envsetup.sh
lunch 1
mmm screencap
```

Then you will get your executable. And in the building process, you can see how Android build your executable including those g++ command.

**UPDATE**:

> I want to use the code contained within a file such as screencap.cpp as part of a larger ndk-build project in an Android app

Change the Android.mk file under that directory, or you can copy that dir to somewhere else.

Add several statements into it to build a static library.

```
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Then add the static library to your application. It should work.

Comment: Sorry Jermaine, I didn't explain myself as well as I could have. Although your answer is really useful to the question I asked - I'm actually trying to build the code in the isolation of an Android app ndk-build

Comment: I modified a little bit but still cannot get what you mean. This the way how we build Android. Can you make some illustrations on "isolation of an Android app ndk-build"?

Comment: So, the code you posted does indeed build the executable. However, I want to use the code contained within a file such as screencap.cpp as part of a larger ndk-build project in an Android app - not as part of a custom ROM. I have build the shared object the code relies on but haven't been able to correctly the link the system header chain.

Comment: Thanks Jermaine - of course I can do that! obviously didnt think it through :) Great answer

Comment: Sorry Jermaine - that's coming back with "Nothing to be done for 'all modules'." Do you know what this is trying to tell me? - From google search it seems that it's already built so isn't going to build again?

Comment: try rm -rf out/ first @Graeme

Comment: This also deletes all of the dependent libraries :/ (*** no target to make ...crtbegin_dynamic.o)

Comment: In general, it will recompile all its dependent modules. Are you use any 3rd-party cross-compile tool chains? @Graeme

Comment: Nope, apart from the change to the executable everything else is as standard. The dependent libraries do not seem to be linked in the make file as requiring to be built first.

Comment: Sorry, I must be wrong, so a better solution to "Nothing to be done for 'all modules'"  is to change a little bit like adding some spaces to that file and mmm again. @Graeme

Answer (score 0):

(A more streamlined version of @Jermain Xu's answer)

You can modify a module's `Android.mk` in the android source tree and change

```
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

to

```
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

in order to build this module as a Shared Library allowing it to be linked against. It requires a completed full build to link against, but you can then use the `mmm` command to point to the module (the module in this instance is the directory containing the `Android.mk` file).

For instance from the android source base directory,

```
mmm framework/base/cmds/screencap
```

This will echo the location of the built `.so` file which should be linkable in your own app.